# Email notification for PO PR release through workflow in SAP ERP

Tags: workflow, abap, sap-erp

I have created a workflow to send email after PO release . After every release code  a mail is to be sent to the next Releaser to release . Just want to know how to set the Recipient in the email step in workflow? I have maintained the user name against each release code in Release strategy workflow in SPRO.

In the workflow if I enter a specific email id in recipient. Then mails are working. Basically it's working if choose a single Recipient. I want it to choose next Releaser to release the PO.